# Where does the original Droids animated series fit into the pre-Disney canon/chronology?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, chronology

Before Disney took over the *Star Wars* franchise, where was the *Droids* animated series placed in the chronology, is there a canonical date for it, and which events/media (book/film/games, etc.) came immediately before and after it?

Comment: Which raises the question "Does it even have to fit in to any chronology?"

Comment: Star Wars was better when it was 2 hitchhikers that stumbled into major galactic events.  Way better than C3PO being built by some Skywalker kid.

Answer (score 7):

According to [Leland Chee](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Leland_Chee) (Lucasfilm's in-house chronology expert), the Droids TV series exists around 15BBY, 15 years prior to the events of A New Hope.

> **15 BBY for Droids** has been in use since Insider #73 (2003) [See below], if not
> earlier.
>
> 3 ABY for the Ewoks movies have been in use since Behind the Magic
> (1998), if not earlier.
>
> These two timeline positions supercede any timeline positions released
> before those sources. If you have an official source released after
> the publication of the above sources that lists a differerent timeline
> position, let me know.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars Forum - Tasty Taste (AKA Leland Chee)](https://web.archive.org/web/20070305041157/http://forums.starwars.com/thread.jspa?threadID=222689&start=2265)</sup></sub>

---

> *The Droids cartoons take place 15 years before the events of Star Wars: A New Hope and center around the galactic travels of C-3PO and R2-D2 before they meet Luke Skywalker."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: Insider #73](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Insider_73)</sup></sub>